# Coefficients of the first fundamental form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

The question is:
Let $S$ be the paraboloid with equation $z=x^2+y^2$ and let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\times]0, \infty[\to S$ given by $\Phi(u, v) = (u\cos{(v)}, v\cos{(u)}, v^2)$. Compute the coefficients E, F, G of the parametrization $\Phi$.

I know what is supposed to do, but I'm not getting the part of having $\Phi{(u)}$ and $\Phi{(v)}$. Like, is it supposed to separate $\Phi$ in two function, one with $u$ and another with $v$? Thus, I just can advance in the exercise knowing that.

(By the way, didn't get either where does $S$ enter).

Comment: You need to work out the partial derivatives $\Phi_u$ and $\Phi_v$.

Answer (score 1):

You need $\Phi_u$, the partial derivative of $\Phi$ with respect to $u$ (not $\Phi(u)$), and similarly for $v$.

Compute $\Phi_u,\Phi_v$ first. Then, \begin{align*}
E&=\Phi_u\cdot \Phi_u\\
F&=\Phi_u\cdot \Phi_v\\
G&=\Phi_v\cdot \Phi_v\\
\end{align*}

$S$ enters in the definition of the parameterization. The point of $\Phi$ is that it is supposed to be parameterize the surface $S$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!